# Start / Stop Resources of Windows Server Failover Cluster in C#

Tags: c#, windows, server, cluster-computing, failover

I'm looking for a way to manage (start / stop) windows server cluster resources of type "generic service" in Microsoft .NET C#.

Do you guys have any idea?